# Is there a way to show an alternative theme for wordpress visitors?

Tags: wordpress, themes

Is there a way for Wordpress to show an alternative theme to a visitor? I have a few Wordpress sites that need to support different device profiles and formats. If there was a way to switch to an alternative theme, say a mobile theme, by passing in a URL parameter like so,

http://www.site.com/blog/?android=1
http://www.site.com/blog/?ipad=1
http://www.site.com/blog/?minimal=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many plugins that should do that. [This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/iphone-theme-switch/) is just one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Browser-based Theme Plugin](http://code.kuederle.com/browserbasedthemes) to switch following the User-Agent header. That could be updated to add additional parameters including GET parameters.